# Facebook post on timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Twitter has a very simple API for encouraging users to tweet something based on web intents. [See here.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=twitter%20web%20intents&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fdocs%2Fintents&ei=NwSLUObaBeeU2wXdtoHQDA&usg=AFQjCNFx079zUtc2W9dp-zScnF6Pw_N-hA)

Does Facebook have an equivalent? If so, what is it? What I basically need is to let users be able to post a message from my website to either their timeline or a friend's timeline, with facebook itself handling the login authentication stuff. So the use cases would be: 1) user clicks the post link, happens to be logged into FB on his browser, and FB takes them to their timeline with the text already pasted into their status update box; or 2) same as 1, but with an intermediary log in step for a user who didn't happen to be logged in before.

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any Facebook share plugin?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13085564/is-there-any-facebook-share-plugin)

Comment: I don't think so - I'm looking to share text, not a URL.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `link` parameter? need an [example](http://www.fbrell.com/saved/0ce90221f139fc44d15782f1dfad3589)?

Comment: Perfect, thank you. If you'll post an answer, I can go ahead and accept it? I'm not sure how to mark a question as closed.

Comment: Let's wait for the community to close it as duplicate, otherwise I'll go ahead and post it as answer.